# Create Doctrine entity of single table from database in Zend Framework 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have configured doctrine ORM in my ZF2 project and create doctrine entity of whole database. Now, I have added one more table named `dashboard_group` in database. How can I create Doctrine entity for only this table.

I don't want to replace other created entities.

Comment: Are you generating your entities with the doctrine command line tool ?

Comment: yes, but unable to generate single table entity. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Use `–filter` option in your command :

```
./vendor//bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="YourModule\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database --filter="dashboard_group" annotation ./module/MonModule/src/
```

And then to add setter/getter into the generated entity :

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./module/YourModule/src/ --generate-annotations=true --filter="dashboard_group"
```

Comment: I have tried this one ... but following error are coming "No Metadata Classes to process." Please suggest whats going wrong with me.

Comment: How to run the same in windows

Comment: I got the same issue: "No Metadata Classes to process", With both commands shows the the same error @blackbishop

Comment: @blackbishop I changed in my case: `--filter="edificio"` from this: `--filter="Edificio"` just had to uppercase the entity and now it works ok