# Generate Single Entity In Doctrine2 With ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

Hi I've the following commands to generate annotation and entities of mysql database tables in doctrine2 with zend framework 2

Generate annotations with doctrine

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Application\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Application/src/
```

Generate entities with doctrine

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./module/Application/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```

But I'm really not getting that how to generate a single entity with annotations of new created table in database.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `-filter` option. Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29603808/1386551)

Answer (score 2):

I've did it with the following -filter option as suggested by blackbishop

Generate annotations with doctrine For Single Table

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Application\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database --filter="link" annotation ./module/Application/src/
```

Generate entities with doctrine For Single Table

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./module/Application/src/ --generate-annotations=true --filter="link"
```

Where link is my new created table name.

Thanks blackbishop